# Kubernetes: Clone existing volume

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any way to create a new persistent volume claim on basis of a already bound volume? So kind of a like a cloning or copying function?

I searched the web but I only found solutions on how to download content from an existing volume and then upload it to a new one but there has to be a function within kubernetes I think.

Has anyone some ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what do You mean. Can you explain it a bit more, what are you trying to achieve so I can possibly address this.

Answer (score 1):

As of now this feature is not yet stable, but you might give this a try: [Volume Snapshot Alpha for Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/01/17/update-on-volume-snapshot-alpha-for-kubernetes/)